# How to listen when a user has verified his email?

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, ionic2, firebase-authentication

My login page redirects to another page if your email is not verified. This second page is meant to force the user to verify the email. When the page is loaded the verification mail is sent with:

```
this.user.sendEmailVerification();
```

Now the user goes to the email and click the verification link.

How can I set a listener in my code that fires a function once the email has been verified??

Comment: It's not necessary to repeat your tags in the title, especially not in ALL CAPS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can customize the email action handlers as described in [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler).

> Some user management actions, such as updating a user's email address
>   and resetting a user's password, result in emails being sent to the
>   user. These emails contain links that recipients can open to complete
>   or cancel the user management action. By default, user management
>   emails link to the default action handler, which is a web page hosted
>   at a URL in your project's Firebase Hosting domain.
>
> You can instead create and host a custom email action handler to do
>   custom processing and to integrate the email action handler with your
>   website.
>
> The following user management actions require the user to complete the
>   action using an email action handler:
>
> - Resetting passwords
> - Revoking email address changes—when users change their accounts' primary email addresses, Firebase sends an email to their old
>     addresses that allow them to undo the change
> - Verifying email addresses
>
> To customize your Firebase project's email action handler, you must
>   create and host a web page that uses the Firebase JavaScript SDK to
>   verify the request's validity and complete the request. Then, you must
>   customize your Firebase project's email templates to link to your
>   custom action handler.